# AAR file updation when imported and added as a module in an Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I am using a library by importing the `aar` file which creates a module. And this module is then added as a dependency.

I did it for one of the libraries I'm using in my app and it worked fine. But now I want to update to the latest version of the library I'm confused about the following:

1. How do i find out which version I'm using? Don't remember what the version was when i imported the `aar` file. Is there a way to check this?
2. I want to update the aar with its latest version. How do i do that? Do i simply re-import and it will overwrite? or do i delete the existing module and import again?

I found only this one related post on SO and it did not answer any of the above two questions. It suggests another way of using the aar but I want to know how to continue using the import aar approach.

The aar file in question is that of [millennial-media](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-ad-sdk/adding-aar-files.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i find out which version I'm using? Don't remember what the version was when i imported the aar file. Is there a way to check this?

There **isn't a standard way** to know the version of your aar.
You can use the name or a file inside the aar or you can simply use doc.

> I want to update the aar with its latest version. How do i do that? Do i simply re-import and it will overwrite? or do i delete the existing module and import again?

You can simply overwrite the aar file.
Importing the aar file means:

- copy the aar file in a folder
- add the dependency and the repository in the `build.gradle`

Somenthing like:

```
   repositories {
            flatDir {
                dirs 'libs'
            }
        }
```

and add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
   compile(name:'nameOfYourAARFileWithoutExtension', ext:'aar')
 }
```

When you want to update, just copy the aar file overring the exiting file.

I suggest you using a **maven dependency**. In this case someone uploaded the library in a maven repository.
Currently it is the best solution in my opinion.

In this case just add a dependency in your project

```
dependencies{
  compile 'group:name:version'
}
```

and it is very simple to know the version and to update the library.

Comment: the last one is definitely a life saver but this library does not seem to be offering a maven dependency to directly add (at least could not find it in the documentation). Is there a way to search elsewhere?

Comment: It is very hard wo search this kind of info. is this library published in github?

Comment: I guess not. this is the one I'm talking about : http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-ad-sdk/adding-aar-files.html

Comment: In any case you can search the library in the maven central (http://search.maven.org/) or in bintray (https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) using the group name.